# QTP with JQuery Tree

Tags: qtp

We are using an application which make use of JQuery tree and were trying to automate the application. we find the following issues while automating the application, it would be great if anyone could help us for the following queries:

1. To add any group in a tree, we right click on a parent node and select the option "Add Group" to create, QTP doesn't recognize this action. -> we do found out a temporary solutions by adding one line of code with right click event initiated. (It would be great if someone could provide us a permanent solutions).
2. After providing new name for a group, we need to hit the enter button in order to hit the database, the enter key was pressed during our recording session and when same was re-played, QTP didn't recognize the enter key which were pressed.

Hope my queries are clear. It would be appreciated if anyone could provide the solution for the above two queries.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger an enter even you can use below code,

set keyboard = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

keyboard.SendKeys  "{ENTER}"